# Failed to boot ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, 22.04

I have an Asus X507U machine. I tried to install ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS but it failed. Attached are the boot logs.

What is wrong with this? I am suspecting it is due to the graphics card and tried installing with safe graphics which yields nothing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What media are you trying to install from?  Optical media is no longer a recommended installation media & your messages remind me of using *optical* media (which can take >60 minutes to boot! due to *timeouts* with the optical media).  You also didn't specify which 22.04 product you're trying to install (Desktop? Server? or something else?)

Comment: Check your BIOS is up to date. It looks like the latest version is v306: https://www.asus.com/supportonly/x507uf/helpdesk_bios/

Comment: Thanks for replying @guiverc installation media is sony pen drive and the product is for desktop.

Comment: Ok @LiamProven . I will look for the update. Thanks for the suggestion.